# jQuery animate slider

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I have a slider on http://jsfiddle.net/aXVFR/

When I click on an item all the images should rotate. With ONE click it works fine. The next not so good. I've written in the console.log and find duplicates of history data. It should change every time but it does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after checking to see why the images weren't rotating round on every click I decided to simplify you code a little. You shouldn't really need to reset any values, like you were doing with the **reset_history()** function, if you have them stored in arrays, which you did.

All you really need is a variable to track the current front facing item and you can get the necessary "**step**" values you need by doing a quick calculation with that and the "**index**" you were using in the **each** functions.

Here is the edited code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var side_item_count = 2;
    // ADDED CURRENT ITEM VAR
    var currItem = 1;
    var item_count = $("#showcase li").size();
    var history_width = get_history_width();
    var history_height = get_history_height();
    var history_margin = get_history_css("margin");
    var history_zindex = get_history_css("zindex");

    console.log(history_width);
    console.log(history_height);
    console.log(history_margin);

    // REMOVED get_next_index() THROUGHOUT TO SIMPLIFY SPECIFIC CALCULATIONS
    $("#showcase li").live("click", function(){
        if(currItem == item_count){
            currItem = 1;
        }else{
            currItem++;
        }
        step_loop( currItem );
    });

    function step_loop(this_index) {
        $('#showcase li').each(function(index) {
            counter = index + 1;
            step_animate(this_index, counter);
        });
    }

    function step_animate( current_index, counter ) {
        // NEW CALCULATION USING currItem TO WORKOUT NEW ITEM POSITION
        current_object = $('#showcase li:nth-child(' + counter + ')');
        next_index = counter + 1 - currItem;
        if((counter - currItem) < 0){
            next_index = (counter - currItem) + item_count + 1;
            console.log("-- " + next_index);
        }else{
            console.log(counter + " + 1 - " + currItem + " = " + next_index);
        }

        // ADDED NEW VAR next_zindex 
        var next_width = history_width[next_index];
        var next_height = history_height[next_index];
        var next_margin = history_margin[next_index];
        var next_zindex = history_zindex[next_index];

        // ADDED ZINDEX CHANGE BEFORE ANIMATION
        $(current_object).css("zIndex", next_zindex).animate({
            marginLeft: next_margin,
            width: next_width,
            height: next_height,
            }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
        });
    }

    function get_history_width() {
        var width = new Array();
        $('#showcase li').each(function(index) {
            counter = index + 1;
            width[counter] = $('#showcase li:nth-child(' + counter + ')').css('width');
        });
        return width;
    }
    function get_history_height() {
        var height = new Array();
        $('#showcase li').each(function(index) {
            counter = index + 1;
            height[counter] = $('#showcase li:nth-child(' + counter + ')').css('height');
        });
        return height;
    }

    // CHANGED get_history_margin TO SERVE ZINDEX VALUES AS WELL 
    function get_history_css(property) {
        var margin = new Array();
        var zindex = new Array();
        $('#showcase li').each(function(index) {
            counter = index + 1;
            margin[counter] = $('#showcase li:nth-child(' + counter + ')').css('marginLeft');
            zindex[counter] = $('#showcase li:nth-child(' + counter + ')').css('zIndex');
        });
        switch(property){
            case "margin":
                return margin;
                break;
            case "zindex":
                return zindex;
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the live example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aXVFR/3/

You may notice on the jsfiddle update, I've made some changes to the css. This was simply to be able to see more of what was going on with the elements.

I hope that's helpful and not too far removed from your original code!

Comment: It works like magic. Beautiful! I will accept this answer when I've checked the code. Big thanks!

Comment: Great stuff. Glad I could help :)